# Is there a way to prove that $A \setminus C = (A \setminus (B \cup C)) \cup ((A \cap B) \setminus C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Drawing out the Venn Diagrams I know this is true.

$(A \setminus (B \cup C))$ is just all the values that are solely in A.

$((A \cap B) \setminus C)$ is just all the values in both A and B but not in C.

And taking the union of these two leads us to the values that are either only in A or in only A and B (but not C).

I am unsure how to rigorously prove this, however. Would starting off by letting $x \in (A \setminus (B \cup C))$ be a good start?

[Venn Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XjXU.png)

Comment: The usual method for proving set equality $X = Y$ is to proving subset inclusion both ways: $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$. And proving subset inclusion $X \subseteq Y$ is just proving the implication $x \in X \implies x \in Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have it.  It is a proof by cases that :

> - Take *any* $x$ where $x\in(A\smallsetminus(B\cup C))\cup((A\cap B)\smallsetminus C)$.
> - Thus we have that $x\in((A\smallsetminus(B\cup C))$ or $x\in ((A\cap B)\smallsetminus C)$
>
>   - In the left case: $x\in A$ but $x\notin(B\cup C)$. The latter means $x\notin B$ and $x\notin C$. Thus in this case: $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$, which is to say: $x\in A\smallsetminus C$.
>   - In the right case: $x\in(A\cap B)$ but $x\notin C$.  The former means $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Thus in this case: $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$, which is to say: $x\in A\smallsetminus C$.
> - So in each case: $x\in A\smallsetminus C$.
>
> Therefore $(A\smallsetminus(B\cup C))\cup((A\cap B)\smallsetminus C)\subseteq A\smallsetminus C$.

However, that is but half or the proof.

Demonstrating the converse uses the law of excluded middle: "Either $x\in B$ or $x\notin B$, so..."

Comment: For the last statement "therefore..." did you mean $A \setminus C$ at the end?

Comment: @hhhiuw yes, that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

To prove sets $S,\,T$ are equal, i.e. $x\in S\iff x\in T$, you should try to prove both directions of the $\iff$ simultaneously by only using $\iff$ steps. To wit:$$\begin{align}x\in A\setminus C&\iff x\in A\land x\notin C\\&\iff(x\in A\land x\notin B\land x\notin C)\lor(x\in A\land x\in B\land x\notin C)\\&\iff(x\in A\land x\notin B\cup C)\lor(x\in A\cap B\land x\notin C)\\&\iff(x\in A\setminus(B\cup C))\lor(x\in(A\cap B)\setminus C)\\&\iff x\in(A\setminus(B\cup C))\cup((A\cap B)\setminus C).\end{align}$$